# Message Communication between two Independent Applications

Tags: java, jsp, events, servlets, groovy

I have a requirement where a Groovy Application is supposed to send event notifications to another Java Web Application Which will than display that data on
web interface.

- I don't want to use Queues like ActiveMQ or RabbitMQ because this will introduce an extra layer and will be used if no other solution exists.
- An idea have been shared with me that I should expose a web-service from my Java application, which will be consumed by the first application, and the data 
  sent to the web-service will be then received in second application and somehow displayed on it's web interface.

I am not sure how this will work i.e how the data which is received in web-service of second application will be displayed on its web interface.

Kindly help me to figure out the right solution for this task.

Comment: Need a little more info, after the java application receives the data from the groovy application, on whose screen should the web interface with updated information show - 1) the user who initiated the data transfer from the groovy interface to the java app? 2) to some other user who logs in at some point to the java web app?

Comment: this is more about architecture, and you can do this with sockets too. Difficult to answer that question. Have so many ways to do that... You can even do with remote ejb calls, or with pure remote method invocation.

Comment: @sethu : thanx, The option 2, to some user who logs into a the Java Web Application at some point.

Comment: @ThufirHawat 
Transport mechanism is NOT an architecture, it is a implementation detail. He can do it with dozens of mechanisms and every one of them will work just fine.

Comment: @YegorChumakov you are saying that EJB is just a "implementation detail"? you can use EJB with remote calls, and I can guarantee that will have impact in the architecture of the whole program. i'm wrong?

Comment: @ThufirHawat

You are. Transport mechanism, framework is unimportant implementation detail. You could do the same things that you usually do with EJB and remote calls with POJO and HTTP, or with Spring and for instance SOAP. It doesn't matter from the architectural point of view what underlying mechanisms are you using if there is no specific requirements. 
What really matters is that you have sync/async control flow and interaction with other system. So, these functional requirements should determine what technology one will use, not vice versa.

Comment: @YegorChumakov you are wrong; I can say that the architecture of how you transmit a message is different from other. You are confusing implementation with architecture. Read this and learn. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658098.aspx . If you not agree, prove with documents.

Comment: @ThufirHawat
Excellent article by Uncle Bob - 
http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html

I am trying to tell that particular technology of choice has nothing common with the word architecture.  EJB + JPA + Jboss (for instance) is not the architecture it is implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem actually is "how to send notifications from server to browser/mobile client issued by another application".

If you have very strict requirements for latency, then I would suggest to use https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue
It was created by HFT guys to process 6 millions of messages per second in a single thread.

To display events on user's screen please consider using mechanisms like WebSockets, Server Sent Events, Push Notifications, Long polling, whatsoever depending on your requirements ( like browser support ).

Actually in most cases it doesn't matter what transport are you using. Unless you have super strict non-functional requirements like sub microsecond latency you're free to choose any mechanism, e.g. HTTP, JMS.

Try not to over engineer and design your software based on your actual requirements - not on stackoverflow answers.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you' I think Server Sent Events will suit my requirements.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you create an XML representation of the data you wish to transfer to the java web app. On the java web app if using simple servlets, create a new servlet to which you can post this xml. The servlet could then persist this to a database. This can then be retrieved when a user logs in to the web app at some point.
Let me know if you need any more help. I could only answer only so much based on the question. Some more light on the framework the java web app is using and the data you wish to transfer, might make it easier to add more info.

Comment: That would be useful when data is not real time, I need the real time notification data sent to Java Application and then displayed on web. All this has to be real-time with very less room for latency.